# Combining two bytes in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

Having two bytes, how to make a new byte by taking the first 3 bits from the first byte and the last 5 from the second ?

For instance, how would that for `11100000` and `00011111` ==> `11111111` ?

I am using Java.

Comment: Your example is badly chosen, because `11100000 | 00011111 == 11111111`, and I don't think this is what you're after.

Comment: Does `00101000` **operation** `01000110` ==> `00100110`?

Comment: How about describing what you have found about java bit manipulation and where exactly are you stuck? I think the question is a lazy one, just wanting the answer without even trying...but taht's just me. Show what you have researched about the subject and what exactly you don't understand. 

Post a code example of what you are trying to do, comments, etc.

Comment: @irrelephant, yes, it does. I simply need to append the last 5 bits from the last byte to the first 3 of the first byte

Comment: @Acapulco, I've initially done how @Björn suggested, but that gave me `-1`, which did not seem good.

Comment: well ``11111111`` as byte is ``-1``

Comment: Still, you are not explaining what you have researched. Where and why are you stuck, what have you tried, etc. 

This should be a good read:
http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before

Comment: @Acapulco, thanks! Will consider in the future. I would have accepted this if it were an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`byte b1, b2;`

take first 3 bits: `b1 & 0xE0`

take last 5 bits: `b2 & 0x1F`

concatenate: `b1 | b2`

Comment: Java will allow: `byte b1 = (byte)0xE0, b2 = 0x1F, b3 = (byte)(b1 | b2);` Which gives `-1`. Is that fine ?

Comment: Yes, see Hachi's comment under your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class. There's an example in [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=378).

Answer (score 2):

Using the masks `0xE0` (11100000) and `0x1F` (00011111), you can mask out the bits you don't want and bitwise or them together:

```
byte b1 = 123; // 01111011
byte b2 = 50;  // 00110010

byte b3 = (b1 & 0xE0) | (b2 & 0x1F);  // = 114  01110010
```