# Concatenating 2 bytes in Java efficiently

Tags: java, byte, concatenation

I am working on a program where I am trying to reduce the amount of memory allocated, I previously use to concatenate strings but the problem was that I do this process several million times and the more I did it the longer it took to allocate these strings. Instead now I am trying work with bytes. I want to do something like this:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[5];
byte cat = arr[0] + arr[1]  //this addition would give me an error obviously. It's for demostration purposes

System.out.println(cat);
```

I just want to take the first byte and put the second one right after it without using any form of String Class as it requires more overhead to concatenate strings as such. Is there a way I can do this with minimal operations?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947138/combining-two-bytes-in-java)

Comment: What do you want to concatenate the bytes into?  Your code shows you trying to concatenate them into a single `byte`, which doesn't make much sense.  Two bytes could make a `byte[2]`, a `short`, or a `char`.

Comment: You'd have to create a byte array (or, as others have mentioned, pack up to 8 bytes together into a larger primitive, like a short, int, or long). But, when your string concatenation was taking too long -- were you using StringBuilder, or `+`?

Comment: What do you mean "take the first byte and put the second one right after it"? Do you mean in an array, or combine the bytes as a high and low byte in a  short integer?

Comment: I was using + " "; @yshavit

Comment: like taking two separate numbers like 1 and 2 and instead of adding them I just make it 12. @Samuel

Comment: You can try simply string concatenation

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Bytes don't work like that.  Two bytes are just two bytes unless you decide you want them to be something else like a `char` or `short`.

Comment: Your + was likely an O(n^2) operation. You should use StringBuilder rather than straight concatenation. I don't have a link handy, but I'm sure there's a question about that on this site. Search for StringBuilder vs concatenation, or similar.

Comment: I was doing string concatenation @IccheGuri which is what I am trying to avoid because I do this millions of times and it slows down the program when I have to allocate space for a new string each time....

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber I think this might be an [**XY Problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). At a guess, if you concatenate strings millions of times, and it causes a noticeable performance issue, then you're likely doing `String = String + String` in a loop. Don't. **Use a `StringBuilder`**.

Comment: I am doing exactly that. `String = String + String` I am trying to do anything to avoid doing so which is why I switched from Strings to bytes. I want do so something that doesn't allocate as much memory as making new strings and concatenating them like that  @Andreas

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber As I said, use a `StringBuilder` instead, and don't convert to `String` until you're done concatenating all the pieces.

Comment: ok do you know if Stringbuilder has something similar to .endsWith() function that is found in String ? I use that in conjunction with this. @Andreas

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Have a look at the API yourself: [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new output byte array of the size equal to the sum of all your bytes that are to concatenated in a new byte array using `System.arraycopy()`

As `System.arraycopy()` is native call, it will be certainly faster than String concatenation.

Comment: how expensive is System.arraycopy()?

Comment: System.arraycopy() is the most efficient way of array copying regardless of length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "concatenate" two or more bytes, into a new byte array, just use the [array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) syntax:

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 42;
byte c = 99;

byte[] cat = {a,b,c};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat)); // prints: [1, 42, 99]
```

Your example is however more akin to a `substring()` call, and for that you should use `Arrays.copyOfRange()`, e.g.

```
byte[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1};

byte[] cat = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat)); // prints: [5, 4]
```

Comment: I don't want a new array I just want a new byte and not using any string methods to concatenate the two values.

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber But two bytes cannot be stored in a single byte. You can "add" them, but you're specifically asking to concatenate them. A byte is 8 bits long. If you have two bytes (8+8=16 bits), you simply cannot store that in only one byte. Your request is impossible.

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber It's the same as concatenating two strings. If the first string is 3 long and the second string is 5 long, the concatenated string is 8 long. The size of the concatenation is the **sum** of the sizes of the values being concatenated.

Comment: ok I see what you mean and why what i wanted to  doesn't make sense.